# Elastic Beanstalk Deployment - Verify the permissions on the environment's service role

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

I have working with a laravel 8 application and attempting to deploy it using elastic beanstalk. One day without any warning I have been getting the below error and I cannot seem to figure it out at all. It is even stumping the AWS support. I have tried pretty much everything and the advice I keep seeing it to make sure the permissions on the security section work.

[image: Config Settings]

These are the settings I am seeing and I keep switching between the two and adding/removing permissions to try to make it work with either one with zero luck. I have also tried cloning and rebuilding which did not work.

Currently I have the following permissions on the service role:
[image: Service Role Permissions]

And the following for the EC2 role:
[image]

Error on Elastic Beanstalk:
Failed to check health. Verify the permissions on the environment's service role and try again later. Permissions changes take up to two hours to propagate.

Log text included here as well:

```html
----------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-engine.log
----------------------------------------
2021/06/03 14:08:39.967837 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl daemon-reload
2021/06/03 14:08:40.048241 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl reset-failed
2021/06/03 14:08:40.052686 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-enabled aws-eb.target
2021/06/03 14:08:40.056696 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl enable aws-eb.target
2021/06/03 14:08:40.136288 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start aws-eb.target
2021/06/03 14:08:40.141001 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl enable healthd.service
2021/06/03 14:08:40.220221 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf healthd.service
2021/06/03 14:08:40.225894 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-active healthd.service
2021/06/03 14:08:40.229958 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start healthd.service
2021/06/03 14:08:40.251790 [INFO] Copying file /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/healthd/healthd_logformat.conf to /var/proxy/staging/nginx/conf.d/healthd_logformat.conf
2021/06/03 14:08:40.253224 [INFO] Copying file /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/healthd/healthd_nginx.conf to /var/proxy/staging/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/healthd.conf
2021/06/03 14:08:40.255003 [INFO] Executing instruction: configure php-fpm
2021/06/03 14:08:40.260685 [INFO] Executing instruction: configure log streaming
2021/06/03 14:08:40.260695 [INFO] log streaming is not enabled
2021/06/03 14:08:40.260699 [INFO] disable log stream
2021/06/03 14:08:40.260712 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf amazon-cloudwatch-agent.service
2021/06/03 14:08:40.270003 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl stop amazon-cloudwatch-agent.service
2021/06/03 14:08:40.275398 [INFO] Executing instruction: GetToggleForceRotate
2021/06/03 14:08:40.275422 [INFO] Checking if logs need forced rotation
2021/06/03 14:08:40.275441 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:539550674720:stack/awseb-e-nssafrgize-stack/a1fd7df0-9330-11eb-8d1c-0edd3867f3f1 -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region us-east-1
2021/06/03 14:08:40.895708 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:539550674720:stack/awseb-e-nssafrgize-stack/a1fd7df0-9330-11eb-8d1c-0edd3867f3f1 -r AWSEBBeanstalkMetadata --region us-east-1
2021/06/03 14:08:41.486133 [INFO] Procfile not found. Generating default rsyslog config
2021/06/03 14:08:41.487637 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl restart rsyslog.service
2021/06/03 14:08:41.511223 [INFO] Executing instruction: PostBuildEbExtension
2021/06/03 14:08:41.511252 [INFO] Starting executing the config set Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild.
2021/06/03 14:08:41.511266 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:539550674720:stack/awseb-e-nssafrgize-stack/a1fd7df0-9330-11eb-8d1c-0edd3867f3f1 -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region us-east-1 --configsets Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2021/06/03 14:08:41.894764 [INFO] Finished executing the config set Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild.

2021/06/03 14:08:41.894795 [INFO] Executing instruction: CleanEbExtensions
2021/06/03 14:08:41.894818 [INFO] Cleaned ebextensions subdirectories from app staging directory.
2021/06/03 14:08:41.894836 [INFO] Executing instruction: RunAppDeployPreDeployHooks
2021/06/03 14:08:41.894846 [INFO] The dir .platform/hooks/predeploy/ does not exist in the application. Skipping this step...
2021/06/03 14:08:41.894851 [INFO] Executing instruction: stop X-Ray
2021/06/03 14:08:41.894855 [INFO] stop X-Ray ...
2021/06/03 14:08:41.894868 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf xray.service
2021/06/03 14:08:41.902075 [WARN] stopProcess Warning: process xray is not registered 
2021/06/03 14:08:41.902095 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl stop xray.service
2021/06/03 14:08:41.909722 [INFO] Executing instruction: stop proxy
2021/06/03 14:08:41.909742 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf httpd.service
2021/06/03 14:08:41.917202 [WARN] deregisterProcess Warning: process httpd is not registered, skipping...

2021/06/03 14:08:41.917224 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf nginx.service
2021/06/03 14:08:41.923452 [WARN] deregisterProcess Warning: process nginx is not registered, skipping...

2021/06/03 14:08:41.923466 [INFO] Executing instruction: stop php-fpm
2021/06/03 14:08:41.923477 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf php-fpm.service
2021/06/03 14:08:41.928491 [WARN] stopProcess Warning: process php-fpm is not registered 
2021/06/03 14:08:41.928520 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl stop php-fpm.service
2021/06/03 14:08:41.933414 [INFO] Executing instruction: FlipApplication
2021/06/03 14:08:41.933806 [INFO] create soft link from /var/app/current/ to /var/www/html
2021/06/03 14:08:41.933835 [INFO] Executing instruction: start X-Ray
2021/06/03 14:08:41.933841 [INFO] X-Ray is not enabled.
2021/06/03 14:08:41.933846 [INFO] Executing instruction: start php-fpm
2021/06/03 14:08:41.933987 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf php-fpm.service
2021/06/03 14:08:41.942554 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl daemon-reload
2021/06/03 14:08:42.028789 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl reset-failed
2021/06/03 14:08:42.033188 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf php-fpm.service
2021/06/03 14:08:42.038374 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-active php-fpm.service
2021/06/03 14:08:42.041918 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start php-fpm.service
2021/06/03 14:08:42.172017 [INFO] Executing instruction: start proxy with new configuration
2021/06/03 14:08:42.172049 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/nginx -t -c /var/proxy/staging/nginx/nginx.conf
2021/06/03 14:08:42.198193 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c cp -rp /var/proxy/staging/nginx/* /etc/nginx
2021/06/03 14:08:42.200700 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf nginx.service
2021/06/03 14:08:42.207540 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl daemon-reload
2021/06/03 14:08:42.283504 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl reset-failed
2021/06/03 14:08:42.287860 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf nginx.service
2021/06/03 14:08:42.293123 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-active nginx.service
2021/06/03 14:08:42.296696 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start nginx.service
2021/06/03 14:08:42.335235 [INFO] Executing instruction: configureSqsd
2021/06/03 14:08:42.335251 [INFO] This is a web server environment instance, skip configure sqsd daemon ...
2021/06/03 14:08:42.335256 [INFO] Executing instruction: startSqsd
2021/06/03 14:08:42.335260 [INFO] This is a web server environment instance, skip start sqsd daemon ...
2021/06/03 14:08:42.335264 [INFO] Executing instruction: Track pids in healthd
2021/06/03 14:08:42.335269 [INFO] This is an enhanced health env...
2021/06/03 14:08:42.335282 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p ConsistsOf aws-eb.target | cut -d= -f2
2021/06/03 14:08:42.342372 [INFO] cfn-hup.service php-fpm.service healthd.service nginx.service

2021/06/03 14:08:42.342398 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p ConsistsOf eb-app.target | cut -d= -f2
2021/06/03 14:08:42.347355 [INFO] 

2021/06/03 14:08:42.347479 [INFO] Executing instruction: RunAppDeployPostDeployHooks
2021/06/03 14:08:42.347492 [INFO] The dir .platform/hooks/postdeploy/ does not exist in the application. Skipping this step...
2021/06/03 14:08:42.347496 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2021/06/03 14:08:42.347636 [INFO] Platform Engine finished execution on command: self-startup

2021/06/03 18:20:32.502185 [INFO] Starting...
2021/06/03 18:20:32.502245 [INFO] Starting EBPlatform-PlatformEngine
2021/06/03 18:20:32.502262 [INFO] reading event message file
2021/06/03 18:20:32.502366 [INFO] no eb envtier info file found, skip loading env tier info.
2021/06/03 18:20:32.502438 [INFO] Engine received EB command cfn-hup-exec

2021/06/03 18:20:32.709872 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:539550674720:stack/awseb-e-nssafrgize-stack/a1fd7df0-9330-11eb-8d1c-0edd3867f3f1 -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region us-east-1
2021/06/03 18:20:33.065405 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:539550674720:stack/awseb-e-nssafrgize-stack/a1fd7df0-9330-11eb-8d1c-0edd3867f3f1 -r AWSEBBeanstalkMetadata --region us-east-1
2021/06/03 18:20:33.410133 [INFO] checking whether command tail-log is applicable to this instance...
2021/06/03 18:20:33.410147 [INFO] this command is applicable to the instance, thus instance should execute command
2021/06/03 18:20:33.410151 [INFO] Engine command: (tail-log)

2021/06/03 18:20:33.411133 [INFO] Executing instruction: GetTailLogs
2021/06/03 18:20:33.411140 [INFO] Tail Logs...
2021/06/03 18:20:33.412111 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/eb-engine.log
```

Comment: What does the roles trust policy look like?

Comment: Please see below:
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "sts:ExternalId": "elasticbeanstalk"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

Comment: `{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "sts:ExternalId": "elasticbeanstalk"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: That trust policy and `AdministratorAccess` policy should give eb access to anything so i dont think its permissions. Dont see anything remarkable in the log above. Do you have nginx/fpm logs in cloudwatch? Also describe how its failing - no response at all, is there any HTTP communication but no response or the wrong response? (edit your question to add extra info :)

Comment: This answer should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77743069/12326605

Answer (score 1):

Too late, but I hope it helps someone else. Based on my findings, the primary reason for this behavior is:

`"Unable to assume role "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role". Verify that the role exists and is configured correctly."`

Despite having sufficient permissions, the Elastic Beanstalk (EBS) environment is unable to assume the default "aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role" for some reason. The solution was to create a new service role with permissions similar to "aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role" and configure the Elastic Beanstalk environment's service role to use this custom role.

In my case, the environment's health status was transitioning to the "Suspended" state because Elastic Beanstalk couldn't access the environment's service roles for monitoring health, leading to the halting of the deployment.